# Acesso livre a materiais mediante inscrição no YouTube

Tags: autenticação, youtube-api

Entrei no seguinte site:

[Velosofy.com](https://www.velosofy.com/download/intro-template-110)

Neste site o interessado em baixar algo desejado deve clicar num botão para se inscrever no canal do YouTube para ter acesso ao material. E quando o usuário faz a inscrição no site do YouTube, ele tem livre acesso ao material.

Enfim, quais são os requisitos necessários para se conseguir este tipo de site? Como é possível criar este tipo de autenticação?

Tem algo com [API YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo este post do [stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845622/youtube-api-v3-detect-if-subscribed-to-a-channel):

Utilize o método `subscriptions#list` com a variável `mine = true` e o ID do canal que deseja checar em `forChannelId`. Se o usuário logado não estiver inscrito no canal o método retornará uma lista vazia.

Este [outro post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993738/youtube-api-check-for-user-was-subscribed) sugere um exemplo:

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=id&mine=true&key={API_YOUTUBE}
```